# method to check all the time in DB

Tags: android, database

I'm working on android using map, In simple way my application has two users " Driver, Passenger" when the driver click "Start trip" button his location shown to all passenger and when he moved his marker move with him and update his location in the DB.
So, i need method that check all the time if his location change to update the new location in DB.

NOTE: i'm using external DB isn't local DB

Comment: Like this? https://www-staging.firebase.com/blog/2014-08-26-geofire-goes-mobile.html

Comment: yes, it's helpful, but if the driver change his location i need to update the (latitude,longitude) in Firebase, my problem is how can i check all the time on Firebase using android to check if the driver change his location?

Comment: You need a locationlistener on the Android device. Then on updates, you replace the firebase data

Answer (score 1):

Well You have to implement location listener and request location update or use third party library to do heavy lifting for you. Read this 
[How can I get continuous location updates in android like in Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500765/how-can-i-get-continuous-location-updates-in-android-like-in-google-maps)