# 4 Ways get Location all return null with Device Location set to On (Wifi & GPS)

Tags: android, location

Edit: I've drop the working code here. Everybody can just copy paste to run the code. And it's now 4 ways to get Location, but result is null.

I've tried more than 5 code about location, but mostly, there's 3 ways to access location data with Android. All these code return null. The Device Location (GPS and WIFI) is turned on. Have set permissions on AndroidManifest.xml. I've tried on the real device and the AVD emulator, with the same result: **return null**. Can anybody enlighten me what is wrong with the code? All are working code (in my computer).

## 1. LocationManager & LocationListener

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        };

        String coarse = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION";
        String fine = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION";
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, coarse) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{coarse}, 101);
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, fine) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{fine}, 102);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, (android.location.LocationListener) locationListener);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("LATITUDE: " + location.getLatitude());
            System.out.println("LONGITUDE: " + location.getLongitude());
        } else {
            System.out.println("LOCATION IS NULL");
        }
    }
}
```

## 2. FusedLocationProviderClient

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient locationClient;

    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000; /* 2 sec */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    // Trigger new location updates at interval
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        // Create the location request to start receiving updates
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        // Create LocationSettingsRequest object using location request
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

        // Check whether location settings are satisfied
        // https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient
        SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
        settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest);

        // new Google API SDK v11 uses getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        String coarse = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION";
        String fine = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION";
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, coarse) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{coarse}, 101);
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, fine) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{fine}, 102);
        }
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        // do work here
                        onLocationChanged(locationResult.getLastLocation());
                    }
                },
                Looper.myLooper());
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // New location has now been determined
        String msg = "Updated Location: " + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

## 3. FusedLocationApi

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    protected static final String TAG = "main-activity";
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected Location mLastLocation;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses {@code #addApi} to request the LocationServices API.
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // Gets the best and most recent location currently available, which may be null
        // in rare cases when a location is not available.
        String coarse = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION";
        String fine = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION";
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, coarse) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{coarse}, 101);
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, fine) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{fine}, 102);
        }
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            System.out.println("LATITUDE: " + mLastLocation.getLatitude());
            System.out.println("LONGITUDE: " + mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            // It is possible that the user presses the button to get the address before the
            // GoogleApiClient object successfully connects. In such a case, mAddressRequested
            // is set to true, but no attempt is made to fetch the address (see
            // fetchAddressButtonHandler()) . Instead, we start the intent service here if the
            // user has requested an address, since we now have a connection to GoogleApiClient.
        } else {
            System.out.println("LOCATION IS NULL");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
        // attempt to re-establish the connection.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

## 4 SmartLocation lib: compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.9'

```
public class Location1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        System.out.println("ON LOCATION1ACTIVITY");

        SmartLocation.with(this).location()
                .oneFix()
                .start(new OnLocationUpdatedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationUpdated(Location location) {
                        if (location == null) {
                            System.out.println("LOCATION IS NULL");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("LATITUDE: " + location.getLatitude());
                            System.out.println("LONGITUDE: " + location.getLongitude());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500765/how-can-i-get-continuous-location-updates-in-android-like-in-google-maps/41501799#41501799

Comment: not work, Hitesh. My code: 
`SmartLocation.with(this).location()
                .oneFix()
                .start(new OnLocationUpdatedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationUpdated(Location l) {
                        if (l == null) {
                            Sout("LOC IS NULL");
                        } else {
                            Sout("LAT: " + l.getLatitude());
                            Sout("LNG: " + l.getLongitude());
                        }
                    }
                });`

Comment: Were you able to achieve what you wanted?

Comment: Not working. I've using the appropriate code from the github. I've set System.out.println, but nothing printed on the logcat.

Comment: Make sure your application does have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION (both) to have accurate results. Don't forget to ask for permissions at runtime for Android 6.0 and above.

Comment: Please read again my question, I've set the permissions. COARSE, FINE, INTERNET.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution!
I've downgrade the AVD image to Android 8.0 (SDK platform 26) Google Play Intel x86 Atom Sistem Image. Previously, I use Android API 27 Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image. Now all above code works fine, except code #1.

My Detailed Info:
AndroidManifest.xml uses-permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Check and Request Permissions on .java file:

```
String coarse = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION";
String fine = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION";
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, coarse) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{coarse}, 101);
}
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, fine) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{fine}, 102);
}
```

Project build.gradle dependencies classpath:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

Module build.gradle: 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.ts.gov.lesson3"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.9'
}
```

Hope this will help people who have same problem. I've spent days trying to solve this problem. If you wonder why my physical device cannot use the location too, same with me. Just code #4 work using my phone, until I downgrade to AVD Oreo 8.0 with SDK 26.