# Android: FusedLocationProvider, get location every few seconds

Tags: java, android, gps, android-gps

I'm making an app that tracks the user's location and ultimatly uploads it to a Firebase server.

I have created a simple app that displays the location when I press a button on screen. The problem is that it doesnt change the location when I press it again after I walked a few meters (I do get a new location when I re-enter the app though). What do I need to add in order for the app to update the location every X seconds? This is my activity:

```
package com.example.gpstest;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FusedLocationProviderClient client;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        requestPermission();
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.getLocation);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

                    return;
                }
                client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                        if(location != null){
                            TextView lat = findViewById(R.id.location1);
                            TextView lon = findViewById(R.id.location2);
                            TextView alt = findViewById(R.id.location3);
                            lat.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
                            lon.setText(Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
                            alt.setText(Double.toString(location.getAltitude()));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void requestPermission(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check out the answer for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500765/how-can-i-get-continuous-location-updates-in-android-like-in-google-maps).

Answer (score 0):

Because you get the location from getLastLocation. For that you have to implement LocationCallback.

[consider this link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates#java) for more information

Answer (score 0):

// implement these interface in your class 
 GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener.
//than use this code

public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

```
    Location mLastLocation = null;
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more precise.
            return;
        }
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        }

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); //5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000); //3 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F); //1/10 meter

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    } else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

}
```